# Unity Trash Dash Endless Runner game can't add mixamo avatar

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, avatar, mixamo

Hi i downloaded the Trash Dash( the sample game from Unity for endless runner). I want to add new characters. I created a character in Mixamo, but each time i run the app i get an error. ( the app starts, the cat appears, but when i want to switch to the new character it fails. I would really need to help figuring why this happens.

The mixamo animation:

[image]

The new character:

[image]

The error i get :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i copy pasted the prefab character from the cat, and when i tried to add another avatar(which was more complex than the cat, i got the bones don't match error).Even though i changed a lot about that character prefab it was not enough. The fix was to delete the copy version and create new one from scratch.